# CSS - If I use top or margin-top scrollbar not show all content in full height div - [Screenshot]

Tags: css, height, scrollbar, fullscreen, margin

I design a single page web site with full width div without body scrollbar.
but I use scrollbar in div. And ı have a menu.
When I use top or margin-top in my div not show all content with full-height

```css
  .portfolio-content {
    position: relative;
    height:100vh;
    margin-top: 70px;
    }
   .portfolio-item {
      background: #fff;
      padding: 10px;
      @include shadow;
      margin: 15px 0;
     }
      img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 200px;

      }
```

```html
<div class="portfolio-content">
              <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="portfolio-item">
                  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=2&txt=300×250&w=300&h=250" alt="">
                  <div class="portfolio-item-title">
                    www.example.com
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
  </div>
```

[[image: 1]]

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/6YzMs9r.jpg?1

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused but can you try to adjust height:100vh; (increase) and check ?

Comment: I try this but responsive is not working good. But ı found a solution:

    height: calc(100vh - 150px); -> max-width:991px
    height: calc(100vh - 70px); min-width:991px :)